# At which point does the damage boost from power ring take affect?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-3

Eunies default class is the Medic Gunner, which has the art [Power Ring](https://xenoblade.fandom.com/wiki/Power_Ring). Power Ring increases the damage of those within the circle. Occasionally when I perform an art, my  unit will step outside of the power ring circle; or the power ring circle will go away prior to landing the art.

At which point does the boost from power ring take affect? Does the boost take affect when the art is *used* or when the art *hits* the enemy? Ie. If the power ring disappears in the middle of an art, does the damage boost still apply?

Comment: I was also wondering how this works with attacks like Roasty-Toasty that involves a continuous damage thing.

Comment: @Batophobia I'm not far enough into the game to be able to use Roasty-Toasty, so not really sure how that would either

Comment: Based on previous games, damage modifiers are taken into consideration when the move hits, and damage-over-time effects are only based on the initial damage dealt. But these are guesses and so aren't good enough for an answer.

Comment: I think this ability adds a buff you can see on the characters bar, so if they have the buff when the attack connects that should be sufficient.

Comment: @Seiyria Yes there is a buff icon, but that’s the point of the question. Does the buff apply when the attack connects or when the attack is used. When I was playing last night, I noticed that when using an attack that has increased damage with back strike, the boost still applied when connecting despite the enemy quickly shifting so that it would’ve connected on its side. So I might have answered my own question, but don’t think I have enough solid evidence to support it